# find command works not on java, but in system shell

Tags: java, linux, shell, find, filesystems

In a Java programm I want to find the path a hidden file `.file.xyz` in the directory `/my/dir`. This contains a sub-folder which should not be searched, the `excludedFolder`.
So I search for this file with `find`. I exclude the desired folder with `-prune`.

```
String findCommand = "find /my/dir -path /my/dir/excludedFolder -prune -o -name .file.xyz -print";
try{
   Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(findCommand);
   BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
   //nothing is shown here, but hsould
   bufferedReader.lines().forEach(System.out::println);
}catch(Exception e){
    System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

If I paste the command in the terminal and execute it there. It works fine.
My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.
Could you please explain me why?

Comment: it depends which on which path you want to execute it. Just for surety, may be you can try absolute path

Comment: A workaround can be putting this command in a shell-script and try executing the same from Java code.

Comment: @AmanChhabra `/my/dir` is already an absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke "sh" and pass to that program your piped command.
Try:

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder( "/bin/sh", "-c",
               "find /my/dir -path /my/dir/excludedFolder -prune -o -name .file.xyz -print" );
```

Comment: Awesome. It Works . :)

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong `exec()` function of [the `Runtime` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html).

Given

```
String findCommand = "find /my/dir -path /my/dir/excludedFolder -prune -o -name .file.xyz -print";
```

the Java code

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(findCommand);
```

will try to run the file literally named `"find /my/dir -path /my/dir/excludedFolder -prune -o -name .file.xyz -print"` as the command.

You want to pass arguments to `find`, not run some long command that has a filename that looks like a command.  To do that, you need to pass a `String` **array** to `exec()`:

```
String findCommand[] = { "find", "/my/dir", "-path",
    "/my/dir/excludedFolder", "-prune", "-o", "-name", ".file.xyz", "-print" };
...
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(findCommand);
```